# detection of key press when plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to detect pressing of key when plotting position of pendulum and getting position of pendulum to variable, when the key is being pressed. I have no idea how to do it, I tried to search, but I have not found anything helpful. I tried to use `WindowKeyPressFcn` callback, but I cannot find a way to use it. I tried this way:

```
function keyPressCallback(source,eventdata)
    keyPressed = eventdata.Key;
    if strcmpi(keyPressed,'space')
        disp('success');
    end
end

set(f,'WindowKeyPressFcn',@keyPressCallback);
```

But I get an error when running the script:

> There is no WindowKeyPressFcn property on the Root class.

Comment: Please add some of your code and attempts.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Is `f` a figure handle?

Comment: It seems that `f` is zero in your code? Try passing the handle of the figure where you do the plotting.

Answer (score 2):

following Navan's and Cris Luengo's comments, I rearranged the script and it runs successfully for me

```
f = figure;
set(f,'WindowKeyPressFcn',@keyPressCallback);
plot(rand(10,2))
function keyPressCallback(source,eventdata)
    keyPressed = eventdata.Key;
    if strcmpi(keyPressed,'space')
        disp('success');
    end
end
```